# Sudden upthrust confusion

Tags: fluid-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I've never really thought of this but.... whenever solving problems on upthrust, and drawing the free body force diagrams, we don't include the weight of the water on top of the object(by that I mean the normal force of the water on the object downwards)submerged(assuming its completely submerged) and just include the drag, upthrust and the weight... I've thought about it for some time, and I assume its to do with the fact that upthrust is the difference between the forces on the top and bottom of the object(just like in the derivation of upthrust formula)... I hope my question comes across as clear, although I myself find it difficult to explain the question...

Comment: *I assume its to do with the fact that upthrust is the difference between the forces on the top and bottom of the object*  You are correct.

Comment: oh, I guess my worry was all for naught, thanks!